# Dynamic elements reappear after being deleted jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am completely lost here...I want to use jquery to insert and delete comments. Everything works ok until I add a new coment, after that the deleted comments begin to reappear on my page, if I refresh the page, the elements are permanently deleted. I have those two function for inserting and deleting:

```
$(document).on("submit", ".comment_form", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var self=$(this);

    var h=self.serialize();
    var data;
    $.post(self.attr("action"), h, function(returnData){
        data = returnData;
    })
    $(this).ajaxSuccess(function(){
        //alert($(data).find(".vsi-komentarji").html());
        self.parent().next().html($(data).find(".vsi-komentarji").html());
    });

    $(':text', '#comment_form').val('');
    //return false;
});

jQuery.fn.deleteComment = function(turl) {
    $.post(turl, function(){});
    $(this).parents(".comm").slideUp('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    return false;
}
```

I refresh the whole comment section, when a comment is added, since I just need to update the page design and add some ajax so the code behind is the same as it was. You can check the code here: http://dis-slovarcek.ijs.si/ , hope you don't mind its not in english. I also have a big redundancy when searching by letters. I was thinking to put in ajax to load all the details of the password when you click on the arrow, but that only makes the whole thing worse, since then all the details begin to dissapear when I insert a comment.

Comment: Is it possible that the returned data from your `post` request includes the deleted comments? after all, your `deleteComment` method just updates the UI, and not the server

Comment: Yes, the deleteComment deletes the data, if you refresh the page, the comments disapear. This function is called from a form that gets the comment ID and the $.post(turl, function(){}); deletes the element from the database

Comment: I see. in that case- I suggest you run your script in debug mode (using firebug or some such), and take a look at your html after calling `deleteComment` and after calling `submit` to see exactly what elements are added / removed.

Comment: I have been trying to debug this, but the elements get inserted normaly and if I delete them before inserting, they get deleted as expected...but after I insert an element and try to delete it, the css style becomes display:null (because of the slideUp()) and after that it reappears, without the dynamic style generated with jQuery and the element is visible again, but I dont think it ever gets removed...not exactly sure, since this happens quite fast

Comment: I tryed now with remove only, the element does get removed, but it somehow reappears...how is this even possible?